# Aggregating a list and grouping them together in R?

Tags: r

```
df <- USArrests
df$ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
df$Year <- c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2012, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2011, 2015, 2012, 2013)
```

I have the following data. What I would like to do is create a list of all the states, based on their year and ID.

To show it visually, I've made a small mockup in Excel:
[image]

Since Alabama has the year 2017 and the ID 1, it gets put in that cell. The other states Alaska and Arizona similarly has the year 2017 and ID 1, so they get put in the same place. That entire cell will then make up a vector like:

```
c('Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona')
```

When I say "cell", I of course refer to an "element" in the R context. I would like R to fill out all the other elements in a similar way and output it all as a data frame, with ID as observations and year as variables. I really have no idea how to start about doing this though...

Comment: Is this for an arbitrary data wrangling exercise or reporting need? I cannot see how comma separated values within cells help in analysis.

Comment: @Parfait: It's for a reporting. Basically I have a measurement spread over several years in different grouping, and for my analysis I would like to count the numbers of this measurement as well as how many times it occurs depending on the year and grouping (ID). I was under the impression that once I get a list in each element, I can count the number of measurements in each element with the "length" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option can be to use `data.table` and `dcast`. `keep.rownames = TRUE` argument will change the `rownames` to column `(rn)`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)
dcast(df, ID ~ Year, value.var = "rn", fun.aggregate = paste0, collapse = ",")
```

For just number of states solution could be as:

```
dcast(df, ID ~ Year, value.var = "rn",length)
#    ID 2011 2012 2013 2015 2017
# 1:  1    0    1    2    3    9
# 2:  2    1    5    3    3    9
# 3:  3    0    3    2    3    6
```

**Updated based on feedback from OP:**

```
dcast(df, ID ~ Year, value.var = "rn", function(x)paste0("Count: ",length(x),
 " " ,paste(x,collapse = ",")))

# ID                2011                                                        2012                                 2013
# 1:  1           Count: 0                                          Count: 1 California          Count: 2 Colorado,Louisiana
# 2:  2 Count: 1 Washington Count: 5 Minnesota,Mississippi,New Hampshire,Ohio,Wisconsin Count: 3 New Jersey,Oklahoma,Wyoming
# 3:  3           Count: 0                        Count: 3 Hawaii,Kentucky,South Dakota             Count: 2 Idaho,Tennessee
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to use the length command to find the number of states in each element afterwards? I've tried something like length(df) but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: yes. we can do that. How will you like to show the count? Please provide an example.

Comment: So for instance, if the element for the year 2017 and ID = 1 has the 3 states Alabama, Alaska, and Arizona, then I would like R to simply tell me how many states there are in that element. So it will output the number "3" in that element.

Comment: @WoeIs Have a look at updated answer. Probably you want something like that. Do you just want number of state in that cell?

Comment: That was perfect! Just how I wanted it, thank you very much!

Comment: @WoeIs Happy it worked for you. You can accept the anser so that it will be helpful for future users.

Answer (score 2):

Reshape2 with paste works:

```
df$state <- rownames(df)

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID ~ Year, value.var = "state", fun.aggregate = paste, collapse = ",")
# ID       2011                                               2012                        2013
# 1  1                                                    California          Colorado,Louisiana
# 2  2 Washington Minnesota,Mississippi,New Hampshire,Ohio,Wisconsin New Jersey,Oklahoma,Wyoming
# 3  3                                  Hawaii,Kentucky,South Dakota             Idaho,Tennessee
# 2015
# 1         Arkansas,Georgia,Michigan
# 2 Nevada,North Dakota,West Virginia
# 3    Kansas,South Carolina,Virginia
# 2017
# 1              Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Connecticut,Delaware,Florida,Maine,Maryland,Massachusetts
# 2 Missouri,Montana,Nebraska,New Mexico,New York,North Carolina,Oregon,Pennsylvania,Rhode Island
# 3                                                      Illinois,Indiana,Iowa,Texas,Utah,Vermont
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked! Would it be possible to use the length command to find the number of states in each element afterwards? I've tried something like length(df) but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: `dcast(df, ID ~ Year, value.var = "state", fun.aggregate = length)`